# Address to a non-static member function with parentheses &(A::m) not work?

Tags: c++

This might be a beginner grammar question, but I couldn't find one in SO.

```
#include<iostream>
class A
{
  public:
     static void sm(){}
     void m(){}
};
int main()
{
    void (*fp1)() = &A::sm;     // 1) fine.
    void (*fp2)() = &(A::sm);   // 2) fine.


    void (A::*fp3)() = &A::m;   // 3) fine.
    void (A::*fp4)() = &(A::m); // 4) error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void A::m()'
}
```

[C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) says the scope resolution operator (`::`) has the highest precedence.

Then why 1) and 2) works fine, but not 4) ?

Comment: For future ref) [some quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75527548/10027592) from cppreference.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumptions about operator precedence are correct, and intuitively you are right that extra parentheses that don't affect precedence shouldn't matter. However, forming a member pointer is explicitly forbidden with intervening parentheses. The only form allowed is `&` followed by the qualified name of the member (an unqualified name is not allowed, either).

See [[expr.unary.op]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary.op#4) (in the post-C++20 standard draft).

In `2)`, you are not forming a member pointer, but a normal function pointer, because `sm` is a static member function. So the rule I mentioned doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 4):

`A::sm` is a well-formed expression on its own, an lvalue that has function type `void()`. When you have `&A::sm`, it first finds `sm` in the scope of `A` then applies the address-of operator. This is why `&(A::sm)` can have `A::sm` parenthesised.

```cpp
void (&fr)() = A::sm;
void (*fp3)() = &fr;
```

Pointers to members like `&A::m` are specially handled: If `&` is followed by a qualified id that names a non-static member, it forms a pointer-to-member. `A::m` by itself is nothing. When it is parenthesised, `(A::m)` is seen on its own which is an error.

Comment: Formally `A::m` also has a type and value category (`void()` and lvalue since [CWG 2458](https://wg21.link/cwg2458)). It's use is just explicitly restricted. So I don't think that reasoning really works. In fact I wonder why parentheses weren't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I found some pages on cppreference.com.
Hope this helps other C++ learners. 
(emphasis mine)

1. [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator)

> 2) If the operand is a qualified name of a non-static or variant member, e.g. &C::member, the result is a prvalue pointer to member function or pointer to data member of type T in class C. Note that neither &member nor C::member **nor even** &(C::member) may be used to initialize a pointer to member.

2. [pointers to data members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members)

> A pointer to non-static member object m which is a member of class C can be initialized with the expression &C::m exactly. Expressions such as &(C::m) or &m inside C's member function do **not** form pointers to members.
> Such pointer may be used as the right-hand operand of the pointer-to-member access operators operator.* and operator->*:

3. [pointers to member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions)

> A pointer to non-static member function f which is a member of class C can be initialized with the expression &C::f exactly. Expressions such as &(C::f) or &f inside C's member function do **not** form pointers to member functions.
> Such pointer may be used as the right-hand operand of the pointer-to-member access operators operator.* and operator->*.